# Hive setup()-like functionality similar to Mapper setup()?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I want to replace a Hadoop job with Hive. My challenge is in Hadoop, I'm using setup() to build a kdtree by reading in reference data (points of interest) from the distributed cache. I then use the kdtree in map() to evaluate distance of the target data against the kdtree.

In Hive, I wanted to use a udf with evaluate() method to determine the distance, but I don't know how to setup the kdtree with the reference data. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I probably don't have the entire answer, so I'm just going to throw out some ideas that might be of help.

- You can add files to the distributed cache in hive using `ADD FILE ...`
- Hive 11+ (*I think*) should let you access to the distributed cache in `GenericUDF.initialize`

  - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-1016 which references...
  - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-3628

So when you initialize the UDF, you might be able to build your kdtree by accessing the file you added in the distributed cache.

Answer (score 0):

Like climbage says `ADD FILE` command adds the file into distributed cache.
You can access the distributed cache in your UDF simply by opening a file which is in the current directory.
   ie... `open( new File( System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/myfile") );`

You can use a ConstantObjectInspector to access the filename in the `initialize` method of `GenericUDF`, where you can open the file and read into memory into your data structure.

The `distributed_map` UDF of Brickhouse does something similar ( https://github.com/klout/brickhouse/blob/master/src/main/java/brickhouse/udf/dcache/DistributedMapUDF.java )

Something like

```
public ObjectInspector initialize(ObjectInspector[] inspArr) {
   ConstantObjectInspector fileNameInsp = (ConstantObjectInspector)inspArr[0];
   String fileName = fileNameInsp.getWritableConstantValue().toString();
   FileInputStream inFile = new FileInputStream("./" + fileName);
   doStuff( inFile ); 
   .....
}
```